# set returned values of function to variables js

Tags: javascript, function, return

How do I set multiple variables to the returned values of a function in javascript?
This method does not work, names is undefined.

```
function data() {
    var names = ["logan", "harry", "josh", "harris", "jacob"]
    var nameFind = "harris"
    return names, nameFind
}

names, nameFind = data()
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

Comment: You need to learn what a comma does in JavaScript and you will realize that that line is doing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions can only return a single value.  The closest you can get to this is to return the values in an array:

```
return [names, nameFind]
```

...and then parse the array in the calling code

```
var result = data()
var names = result[0], nameFind = result[1]
```

Also, depending on the environment you're working in, the most modern versions of JS support de-structuring the returned value inline, like this:

```
[names, nameFind] = data()
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't do [*tuples*](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Tuple). Return an array or object instead.

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to simplify assigning the return values

```js
// array
function data() {
  const names = ["logan", "harry", "josh", "harris", "jacob"]
  const nameFind = "harris"

  return [ names, nameFind ]
}

const array = data()
const names = array[0]
const nameFind = array[1]

// or with destructuring

const [ names, nameFind ] = data()
```

```js
// object
function data() {
  const names = ["logan", "harry", "josh", "harris", "jacob"]
  const nameFind = "harris"

  return {
    names: names,
    nameFind: nameFind
  }

  // or with shorthand property names

  return { names, nameFind }
}

const obj = data()
const name = obj.name
const nameFind = obj.nameFind

// or with destructuring

const { names, nameFind } = data()
```